# Layout Problems - Not able to create layout properly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am creating a layout in android but the problem is layout is not created as same in design.

I want to create layout like below image i.e.

but the problem is my design distort in some devices like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaZPX.png)

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/lay1"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp20"
    >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/kk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/move_stock_bar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />


    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_edit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kk"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp10"
        />


    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/ibMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_edit"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/kk"
        android:layout_below="@id/ibPlus"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can convert it to Constraint layout and add start and end constraints to your views so they don't overlap.

Comment: @mishti i have used the weightsum concept to make appear like the design just replace the viewgroups with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@mishti I have just used this concept to make the design appear to like what you gave. Try this with ImageView using the weight. It displays the same to all screens if we use weight.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:text="Image View"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="start">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
            android:background="#FF0"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
            android:background="#FF0"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ConstraintLayout for complex layout, it provides you more flexiblity. I did the same layout as in the image attached with question. I am using Guidelines, so i can use this same layout on different screen size and it will work fine.
I am using "app:srcCompat" attribute for setting the image because i am using Vector image here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:background="@color/color_black">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_horizontal_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".01" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_horizontal_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".99" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_start"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_mid"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".8" />


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_text_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/color_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical_mid"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal_top">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_iv"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_placeholder" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MOVE STOCK"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline_vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_vertical_mid"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal_top">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_placeholder" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="54dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_placeholder" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```